# Taylor series of $f(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-sx}}{s}ds$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Taylor series of:

$$f(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-sx}}{s}ds$$

at $x_0 = 0$.

I've done:

By fundamental theory of calculus:
$$f'(x)=1-e^{-1x}$$

Which is clearly differentiable by e.g. $n$ times.

What do I need to do to get the expression:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$

Perhaps use $x_0=0$?

Comment: Read the fundamental theorem of calculus more carefully. This is a definite integral. The $x$ you're differentiating with respect to isn't the limit of the integral. Hint: you can differentiate inside the integral.

Comment: @EthanBolker Please clarify the notion regarding fundamental theorem not applying.

Comment: The fundamental theorem tells you about $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x$. See my solution hints.

Answer (score 1):

First note that

$$\frac{1-e^{-sx}}{s} = -\frac 1s \sum_{n=\color{red}1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} (sx)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!} x^n s^{n-1}$$

Now integrate term by term: $$\int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-sx}}{s} \ ds  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!} x^n \int_0^1 s^{n-1} \ ds = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n \cdot n!} x^n$$

Comment: Why does $(-1)^n$ change to $(-1)^{n+1}$?

Comment: Pulling in the minus sign from the previous expression

Answer (score 1):

Given that
$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - e^{-xs}}{s} \, ds$$
then
\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(x) &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{0+s \, e^{-xs}}{s} \, ds = \int_{0}^{1} e^{-xs} \, ds = \left[ - \frac{e^{-xs}}{x} \right]_{0}^{1} = \frac{1 - e^{-x}}{x}
\end{align}
Now, 
\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(x) &= \frac{1}{x} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \, x^{n}}{n!}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, x^{n}}{(n+1)!}
\end{align}
and upon integration
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, x^{n+1}}{(n+1) \, (n+1)!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \, x^{n}}{n \cdot n!}$$

In terms of the desired expression:

$f(x)$ is seen in the form
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{n}(0) \, (x-0)^{n}}{n!}$$
where 
\begin{align}
f^{n}(0) = \begin{cases} 0 & n=0 \\ \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} & n \geq 1 \end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Now how does one see that the final sum is the Taylor series?

Comment: Taylor series are unique. The last expression here is a power series of the right form and must therefore be the relevant Taylor series.

Comment: @mavavilj the form you are looking for has been added for some clarity

Comment: But is $f^n(0)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ for $n≥1$? It seems that one cannot really differentiate to see $f^{n}(0)$ since 0 is not in the domain of the integrand (0 in the denominator). Maybe this is the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just integrate the power series:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{1-e^{-sx}}s\,\mathrm{d}s
&=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-s)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k\,k!}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First let's take care of $x=0$.

$$
f(0) = \int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{s0}}{s} ds = \int_0^1 \frac{1 - 1}{s} ds = 0 .
$$
(the integral looks improper, but isn't really).

Now you have to compute derivatives with respect to $x$:

$$
f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{sx}}{s} ds = 
\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-e^{sx}}{s} ds = 
$$

Can you take it from there?

You might also be able to do this problem by expanding $e^{sx}$ in a power series inside the integral, and then integrating term by term.